How can i set a variable in Reactjs after a callback?
I have the following configured in the front end for react js
 const [allowedUsers, setallowedUsers] = useState([]);
 myService.getusers()
        .then(function (result) {
            if (result.allowedaccess) {
                setallowedUsers(result.allowedaccess);
            }
        });

The problem is that if i debug then i can see that result.allowedaccess is populated , with the array ['bob', 'mary', 'chris'] but if i console.log "allowedUsers" , the variable up top in the const , it is empty it should be an array like the following
  ['bob', 'mary', 'chris']

How can i set the variable ?

"but if i console.log"... just don't do that and you want see anything wrong

To see the updated value of allowedUsers, you can use a useEffect hook to watch for changes:
const [allowedUsers, setallowedUsers] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {
  myService.getusers()
    .then(result => {
      if (result.allowedaccess) {
        setallowedUsers(result.allowedaccess);
      }
    })
}, []); // Empty dependency array ensures this runs once on mount

useEffect(() => {
  console.log('Updated allowedUsers:', allowedUsers);
}, [allowedUsers]); // Runs when allowedUsers changes


what if i wanted to update a second variable ? do i need to put as second useeffect or can i do it with the same one ? and have ...... } , [allowedUsers, devUsers] ?\

You can update multiple state variables within the same useEffect. Just include them in the dependency array of the useEffect if you need to monitor changes to them.
